# how to catch notification Id when we sms notification

Tags: android, notifications

Here  is a code snippet for  notification in my application.this result to a  new notification for every message.but i need a single notification for multiple messages.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

 nBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_indietext_new)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.app_icon_indietext_new))
                        .setContentTitle(senderNum)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            //String Number = nBuilder.toString();

            //create an intent to open  a required activity
           Intent nIntent = new Intent(context, ConvActivity.class);
           nIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            //nIntent.putExtra(_id, threadId);
           nIntent.putExtra(ADDRESS, senderNum);

            //click action  will  be done by  pendingIntent.send intent to the pendingIntent
            PendingIntent nPendingInten = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            nBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.replyyyy, "Reply", nPendingInten);
            String ThreadID = (String) nBuilder.getExtras().get(_id);

            Random random = new Random();
            int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;

            NotificationManager nNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            TaskStackBuilder nStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            nStackBuilder.addParentStack(ConvActivity.class);

            nStackBuilder.addNextIntent(nIntent);
            nBuilder.setContentIntent(nPendingInten);

            Notification n = nBuilder.build();
            n.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
            nNotificationManager.notify(m,n);
```

and,when i open my app,first is the list  of messages.when i click on item it will open the  conversation.upto here it is fine.i want to open same conversation if sender is already in the list.how it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use an uniq indentifier for every uniq user and notify based on that indentifier, if existing on just update, if not is created a new one. maybe you can Use below code to convert sender name to serie of numbers, and use it as id:

```
String str = "abc";  

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); for (char c : str.toCharArray()) sb.append((int)c);
```

Your m value:

```
 BigInteger m = new BigInteger(sb.toString());
```

Hope i had understood correctly your answer, and helps you :)

Comment: thanks mate,but  i think first argument  in  notify() should be integer

Comment: Sorry i missed a line of code ,Its easy to go from Big to int ,   int i = m.intValue();

Comment: I have used in my app for the same purpose and its fine... anyway hope you solve it :)